# Missing character from link Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hyperlink

I have a Link resource. In my view, I have a series of links that people can click to open another web page:

```
<%= link_to link.description, "http://#{link.url}", :target => '_blank' %>
```

If the value of #{link.url} is www.google.com, the link works fine. However, if the value of #{link.url} is http://www.google.com and I click it, it will go to the address http//www.google.com <--- notice it's missing a : after http. Can someone help me remedy this?

Thanks!

Comment: why don't you strip "http://" from your url as you have added it manually there and it will make it consistent

Comment: if I do that, the url becomes http://localhost:3000/opportunities/www.cnn.com

Comment: just initialize another variable with 'http://' and then concatenate it with the link.url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about you add a helper method that checks to see if link.url contains 'http://' or not.

You could use something like this:

```
def link_formatter(url)
 prefix = "http://"
 url.include?(prefix)? url : prefix + url
end
```

That will check to see if link.url contains "http://", if it doesn't it will return the proper format for your url, if it does, it will just return link.url as is.

Comment: thanks! I added that method to my Link model and added a "before_save" callback. However, could you help me understand how to pass the url from the view into the method as an argument? Right now I am getting the error: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: So, you added this method to your model? You would actually want to add this method to either a helper class (if you have other methods you want to expose to your view) or create the method in your controller and expose it as a helper method to your view. To expose the method from the controller to your view you would place that method in your controller, add this to the top of the controller class, `helper_method: link_formatter`, and than in your view just call the method in your link: `<%= link_to link.description, link_formatter(link.url), :target => '_blank' %>`

Comment: Careful with `include?`. You'd be better with: `url.match(%r[\A(https?|mailto)://])` to account for different kinds of URLs.

Comment: @GrahamJackson Thanks - I tried that but I am getting an "undefined method `link_formatter'".. Please advise. I added that method in my Link controller; should I be adding it anywhere else?

Comment: Did you add `helper_method :link_formatter`, to the top of the Link controller?

Comment: i moved the link_formatter method over to my application_helper and it worked @GrahamJackson thanks so much for your help